# Option in arrows.meta in recent TIKz 3.0.1 doesn't work

Tags: tikz-arrows

Recently I upgrade my TikZ installation to version **3.0.1** and observe, that arrows options in arrows.meta doesn't work anymore. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[blue,{Circle[slant=0.3]-Latex[]}]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
%\draw[blue,{Circle[]-Triangle[length=4pt]}]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[blue,{Circle[]-Triangle[]}]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

gives error:

`Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key tikz/Circle[slant', to which you passed 0.3. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Similar errors I receive for any arrow's option.

I use 64-bit MikTeX 2.9. Is this error in MikTeX installation and I need to install pgfkeys separately (from where?) or it is bug in recent TikZ?

Comment: Nevermind the first commented one indeed gives an error.

Comment: Btw: I didn't believe your claim that you get the error from the example, The "slant" clearly indicated that the first line should not be commented.

Comment: Just add a space after `blue,` ;). Weird, but it works. `blue, {` is fine. `blue,{` is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your braces are imho wrong

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz]{standalone}
               \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue,{Circle[slant=0.3]}-{Latex[]}]  (0,1) -- (2,1);
\draw[blue,{Circle[]}-{Triangle[length=4pt]}]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[blue,{Circle[]}-{Triangle[]}]  (0,-1) -- (2,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I don't really see how this is different from my answer ;). But do you have support for the claim that the other syntax is wrong? Because all I could really say was that I'd always used this other syntax and that continues to word. I wasn't sure that the OP's was actually wrong (in the sense that it would be expected to lead to error).

Comment: @cfr I think your answer came seconds before mine... I don't know if the other syntax worked in previous versions, but for me it looks wrong to hide the hyphen in braces ...

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, of course. You wouldn't have seen mine. I was really interested in the claim it was wrong, though. I've always used this syntax, but I can't give any principled explanation for why the other shouldn't work.

Comment: I've edited my answer again. It turns out that the original syntax would work if there was a space after `blue, `. Is it just me or is this extremely odd?

Answer (score 6):

I think Ulrike's view about wrongness is correct as a quick trial-error shows the problem. What happens is that the parser comes to the point after understanding `blue`, parses the remaining part until a comma or `]`
shows up. The blue is first looked up in the key family and if not found in a few places TikZ throws it with the hope that `it must be a color then`. we have

```
\draw[blue,%<- this is a single style candidate 
    {Circle[slant=0.3]-Latex[]}%<-- this is also a single style candidate for the parser
]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
```

Now it looks for `=` and finds one. So this must be a key-value pair. Then separates the two `Circle[slant` being the key and `0.3]-Latex[]` being the value as the error complains.

However, if you limit the brace pairs to each arrow head option then it first finds the `-` and understands that left and right of these are arrowhead specifications. Then sends them to meta parser and it understands `<name>[extra spec]` hence it works properly.

I think this was a bug previously and 3.0.1 fixed it as it is much more meaningful now.

Comment: As I wrote in a comment to cfr's answer I think there is really a bug. The code strips a layer of braces when it shouldn't.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Space gobbling might indeed lead to a bug but I think it is a side effect of using a questionable syntax. When two mistakes are combined it is not the code's fault to work properly in my opinion.

Comment: The additional space *prevents* the stripping of the braces, it doesn't trigger it. Also it has nothing to do with arrows: compare the output of `\tikzset{ {x=y}}` with `\tikzset{{x=y}}`. Both should give "unknown key x=y" but the second doesn't.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Compare the error messages. With the space, it cannot find the key `x=y` which is the wrong way of handling. Without the space version parses properly and gets stuck on unknown `y` hence the one with the space is wrong in both ways. Thus, the brace should be stripped to get the right context. Otherwise most of the TikZ options are impossible to pass the parser. And as my previous comments, both of them are wrong usage because there shouldn't be a brace pair around these options. Hence my previous comment.

Comment: Well in my opinion the handling of the variant *with* the space is correct: `{x=y}` is not "key x with value y" but "key {x=y} without value". The braces are there to hide the equal sign. This is also how it works if a (rather natural) space is before the key, and such a handling would also avoid the arrow problem. I don't know if one can change the behaviour but I added at least a tracker with the description: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/369/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Then there is no way to parse `\node[label={[fill=red]90:a}] {b};` if that wasn't the case. You have to strip the braces sequentially for each hiding. Otherwise you cannot do `\pgfutil@ifnextchar[` stuff which is the bread and butter of TikZ parsing mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

## Summary

This answer now gives the history of my getting to this point. If you just want to make the errors go away and don't appreciate travel logs, here's the bottom line:

Adding a space before the arrow specification apparently allows TikZ to correctly parse it. That is.

```
<colour>, {<Tip>[<key>=<value>]-<Tip>[<key>=<value>]}
```

succeeds where

```
<colour>,{<Tip>[<key>=<value>]-<Tip>[<key>=<value>]}
```

fails.

This is not to say, of course, that the former syntax can be recommended. It may be mere happenstance that it works, and it may be mere happenstance that it will fail horribly next week.

## *Caveat emptor...*

Nonetheless, for now, work it does....

---

## Record of Explorations

I've always used curly brackets at each end of the specification rather than just around the outside. So I can't confirm a change in behaviour except to say that this syntax continues to work fine:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue,{Circle[slant=0.3]}-{Latex[]}]  (0,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw[blue,{Circle[]}-{Triangle[length=4pt]}]  (0,.5) -- (2,.5);
    \draw[blue,{Circle[]}-{Triangle[]}]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: working syntax]

## EDIT

As I say in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266148/option-in-arrows-meta-in-recent-tikz-3-0-1-doesnt-work/266149#comment637738_266150), I don't know if the other syntax is wrong. But I can confirm that I get errors with both the OP's example and [the code percusse posted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266148/option-in-arrows-meta-in-recent-tikz-3-0-1-doesnt-work/266149#comment637734_266148), and I have PGF 3.0.1.

## EDIT EDIT

Looking through the documentation, it is obvious that it is necessary to be quite careful about the syntax here in ways which the documentation never explicitly tells you.

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [arrows={Circle[slant=0.3]-Latex[]}, draw=blue]
    \draw  (0,1) -- (2,1);
    \begin{scope}
      [arrows={Circle[]}-{Triangle[length=4pt]}, draw=red]
      \draw  (0,.5) -- (2,.5);
    \end{scope}
    \draw [green, {[color=orange]Circle[]-[length=6pt]Triangle[]}]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works fine:

[image: working arrows]

Notice that this means that [percusse's explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266152/) must, I think, be too simplistic because it correctly parses

```
green, {[color=orange]Circle[]-[length=6pt]Triangle[]}
```

So it must here see the `-` before dealing with the `=` signs. Merely the fact that the non-parsed expressions contain `=` is not enough, on its own, to cause problems. Moreover, it clearly breaks the specification at the `-`, applying the orange colour only to the left tip and the length adjustment only to the right.

Moreover, we can now add `<key>=<value>` options to the particular tips without error:

```
    \draw [magenta, {[color=orange]Circle[fill=yellow]-[length=6pt]Triangle[width=2pt]}]  (0,-.5) -- (2,-.5);
```

[image: fancier arrow]

This obviously immediately suggests the following possibility:

```
    \draw [purple, {[]Diamond[fill=gray]-[]Triangle[length=12pt]}]  (0,-1) -- (2,-1);
```

which, again, works:

[image: purple variations]

In fact, we can drop the second `[]`:

```
\draw [purple, {[]Diamond[fill=gray]-Triangle[length=12pt]}]  (0,-1) -- (2,-1);
```

produces the same result, again without error.

But now we've gone full circle because it turns out the following works as well:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue, {Circle[slant=0.3]-Latex[]}]  (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[blue, {Circle[]-Triangle[length=4pt]}]  (0,1) -- (2,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: blue arrows]

That is, ***inserting a space between the colour and arrow specification works***.

Comment: I think there is a bug in the key processing. It removes a layer of braces if there is no space before it to "protect" it. Beside the space one can also use two layers of braces: `\tikzset{thick,{{Circle[]-Triangle[length=4pt]}}}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for looking. That's what I was wondering, but I didn't think I understood the parser well enough to guess whether it might be a bug or not.

Comment: I don't know if it is a bug or something that one can't really avoid, but I added a tracker issue anyway: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/369/