# tikz library shadows does not accept space

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgfkeys

With `TikZ` library `shadows`, a space immediately after the curly bracket in `drop shadow = { shadow...` throws an error. If there is no space after the bracket, there is no error, i.e. `drop shadow = {shadow...` works. Is this a bug or is there a rationale behind the intolerance to space?

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I am the key '/tikz/ shadow xshift', to which
 you passed '1ex', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tikzset{test1/.style = {drop shadow = { shadow xshift = 1ex}}}% test1 styles fail
\tikzset{
    test2/.style = {% test2 styles work
        drop shadow = {shadow xshift = 1ex
        },
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[test1] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: TikZ syntax generally is sensitive to spaces - it wants them or wants them not, for example. Sometimes, it is indifferent. But I don't see how you could call it a 'bug'. Is it really a problem?

Comment: @cfr, I am not qualified to say if it might be a bug, a limitation or a feature by design. It seemed strange to me that line breaks and spaces were feasible just about everywhere (see test2) except in one place (see test1). It took me a good 15 minutes to locate the space I had intentionally placed, not knowing it could cause a problem. Also, the error message is sometimes quite scary, along the lines that the tikz shadow command is not recognized.

Comment: As I understand it, it is probably more-or-less inevitable that the parser will sometimes be fussy because of the way in which arguments get bounced around, basically. There are certainly weirder cases than this ;).

Comment: @cfr, I see! Perhaps you can make that an answer: give another example of a weird space-related situation we should be aware of?

Comment: See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266148/option-in-arrows-meta-in-recent-tikz-3-0-1-doesnt-work.

Comment: @cfr, that's an interesting example indeed. It appears, if I read correctly, that a space is needed in that example, whereas here a space is problematic, sort of the opposite situation. What makes it difficult to find information about these issues is that the typical error message goes ``'Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key tikz/... Perhaps you misspelled it.'``. And it's not obvious to the lay user why. Shall I retitle my question with ``Package pgfkeys Error: Perhaps you misspelled it`` and we could string together an answer with related issues, including the one you just quoted?

Comment: I think that would probably make the question too broad ;). As you say, all kinds of things give that error :(. I'm not certain why a space causes a problem in this case, but I assume it must have to do with the stripping of brackets, as it does in the other case even though the effect is, as you say, opposite. I hoped that one of the experts would answer this who could trace through the effect. (I looked at the source, but I don't understand the parser well enough.)

Comment: In your case, the error does actually tell you what is wrong: notice the first space in `/tikz/ shadow xshift`. If it was parsing it as intended, you'd have `/tikz/shadow xshift`.

Comment: @cfr, true, good point, I can see that now, but didn't at the time.

Comment: `\tikzset{test1/.style = {drop shadow = { , shadow xshift = 1ex}}}` works fine.

Comment: @Symbol1, interesting!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reply to @cfr's comment, I think this is a serious problem because people (at least me) love fancy indentation:

> ```
> \tikzset{
>   test1/.style={
>     drop shadow={
>       shadow xshift=1ex
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

In such case, Ti*k*Z got redundant spaces inevitably because of new lines.

Unfortunately, this seems to be a deep bug of pgfkeys. Consider the following example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    option a/.style={
        #1
    }
}
\tikzset{
    option b/.style={
        option a={
            #1
        }
    }
}
\tikzset{
    option c/.style={
        option b={
            red
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\fill[          red ]circle(1);
    \tikz\fill[option a={red}]circle(1);
    \tikz\fill[option b={red}]circle(1);
    \tikz\fill[option c      ]circle(1);
\end{document}
```

It produces two errors: One at `option b={red}`

> ```
> I do not know the key '/tikz/ red '
> ```

And the other at `option c`:

> ```
> I do not know the key '/tikz/  red  '
> ```

One can accumulate spaces as follows

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{option a/.style={ #1 } }
\tikzset{option b/.style={option a={ #1 } } }
\tikzset{option c/.style={option b={ #1 } } }
\tikzset{option d/.style={option c={ #1 } } }
\tikzset{option e/.style={option d={ #1 } } }
\tikzset{option f/.style={option e={ #1 } } }
\tikzset{option g/.style={option f={ #1 } } }
\tikzset{option h/.style={option g={ #1 } } }
\tikzset{option i/.style={option h={ #1 } } }
\tikzset{option j/.style={option i={ #1 } } }
\tikzset{option k/.style={option j={ #1 } } }
\begin{document}
\tikz\fill[option k=red]circle(1);
\end{document}
```

> ```
>  I do not know the key '/tikz/          red          '
> ```

## A partial solution

This trick is so fragile that if one replace `} } }` by `}} }` or `} }}`, the corresponding spaces disappear.

Probably this is the why the source code of Ti*k*Z contains so many lonely `%`. For instance `tikz.code.tex` line 1209-1215

> ```
> \tikzset{
>   no marks/.style={mark=none},%
>   no markers/.style={mark=none},%
>   every mark/.style={},
>   mark options/.style={%
>       every mark/.style={#1}%
>   }}
> ```

## Appendix

`drop shadow` is defined in `tikzlibraryshadows.code.tex`

> ```
> \tikzset{
>   /tikz/drop shadow/.style={
>     general shadow={%
>       shadow scale=1,
>       shadow xshift=.5ex,
>       shadow yshift=-.5ex,
>       opacity=.5,
>       fill=black!50,
>       every shadow,
>       #1
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Here, `general shadow` is `option a`, `drop shadow` is `option b`, and `test1` is `option c`.