# tikz - foreach: trailing spaces in value list not ignored

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code results in the error "key `'/tikz/below '` not known". Apparently tikz ignores leading but not trailing spaces in the value list of `\foreach` loops.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \l in { above} \draw (0,0) -- node[\l]{a} (1,0);
\foreach \l in {below } \draw (0,0) -- node[\l]{b} (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is this to be expected? I didn't find any note in the tikz/pgf manual, and considering the treatment of spaces in comma-separated lists elsewhere in tikz this behaviour is unexpected. Should this be considered a bug? Is it worth a bug report?

Comment: usually spaces are not problem but here it expands `\l` once and immediately compares it within a `\csname .... endcsname` hence it fails. You can expand it so that it strips off the spaces first.

Comment: @percusse Thanks for the analysis. I have no problem with avoiding spaces in the foreach-list, so this is not an immediate problem. However, it would be nice if tikz behaved consistently. So the question remains whether this has to be considered normal behavior or whether it can be fixed with moderate effort.

Comment: The "treatment of spaces in comma-separated lists" comes from `\pgfkeys`: _Any spaces around the `key` or around the `value` are removed_ (p.878, section 82.3 "Setting Keys", pgfmanual v3.0.1a). This  treatment only applies to the key lists. The value lists of `\foreach` are not key lists!

Comment: @PaulGaborit Quite obviously the foreach list does not behave like a key list. Should it behave like that? Given that in other places tikz pays attention to remove spaces, is the observed behavior a bug? At least it belongs to the category of surprising behavior.

Comment: @gernot The real bug is that `\foreach` removes the spaces in front of the values when it should leave all values as they are. ;-)

Comment: @PaulGaborit Ah yes, I haven't yet viewed it this way. Will you write a bug report? ;-) The bottom line for me is that I will continue to put percent signs everywhere as I'm used from plain (La)TeX since one can never be sure which spaces are gobbled and which ones remain.

Comment: What PaulGaborit commented is right, but [not always right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310698). So I personally avoided redundant spaces as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs (or not occurs) in the following way: In `pgffor.code.tex` line 141-149

> ```
> \def\pgffor@iterate{%
>   % Must do all of these in case the internal stack is used.
>   \let\pgffor@last=\pgfutil@empty%
>   \let\pgffor@prevlast=\pgfutil@empty%
>   \let\pgffor@dotsend=\pgfutil@empty%
>   \let\pgffor@dots@pre=\pgfutil@empty%
>   \let\pgffor@dots@post=\pgfutil@empty%
>   % 
>   \expandafter\pgffor@scan\pgffor@values}
> ```

Here `\pgffor@values` is  `above, \pgf@stop ,` or `below , \pgf@stop ,` (notice the space).

- For the first case the `\expandafter` will produce

  ```
  \pgffor@scan above, \pgf@stop
  ```

  and the space before `above` is absorbed  because it follows a control sequence.
- For the second case the space will be there all the way down and eventually become part of `\l`.
  And then, as @cfr, commented: since `\l` will keeps its form until a `\ifx\csname...\endcsname\relax` test is done, `pgfkeys` will find that the key is undefined and fires the `.unknown` handler.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. Regarding my question whether this (to me) unexpected behavior is a bug or feature, it seems that you tend to view it as an (undocumented) feature rather than a bug, right?

Comment: @gernot I rather called them [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It is really TeX's fault that makes handling spaces difficult. For example, we can overcome this by redefine `\def\pgffor@scan!#1,{...}` so the space right after `!` will remain. But then we need extra `\expandafter`.

Comment: I see. So just accept it as one more peculiarity of TeX and friends. Thanks!